# Installation stuck on Nexus 5 (Hammerhead)

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, usb-drive, galaxy-nexus

Am trying to install Ubuntu on a Nexus 5 (Hammerhead) but it's stuck when downloading the file.

I checked my internet connection and everything seems to be fine to me.

Could anyone please explain as to why am having this issue?

I've ran everything regarding the user guide on how to install it but when it comes to the ubuntu-device-flash--channel="ubuntu-touch/devel" --bootstrap --server="http://system-image.tasemnice.eu" am not gettign anywhere fast.

How you can help?

Cheers
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this problem. 
Install CD-AUTO-ROOT (https://download.chainfire.eu/316/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-jflte-jfltexx-gti9505.zip)

Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6OfB6UDNdQ as this will help for gudance.

Make sure you have got SuperSU and MultiROM installed as this is a better way of installing Ubuntu on your phone and also you can still use your Android side as well.

Make sure your phone is on charge and you can use this on Windows/ Mac or Linus (I did it on Linux as it was easier for me)

Hope this helps and problems am more than help to help you out :)

Cheers

Dan